# Endless loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, recursion, infinite-loop

I think I'm pretty close to get it working, but still can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I need to run a function endlessly to swap image src randomly thru a series of 13 or 15 different images, depending on their sizes. This function is working, but just once, it's not running endlessly as I'm planning, without getting a "too much recursive" browser error. Here's the code:

```
function SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize){
    if(imageSize == '110x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*15) + 1};
    if(imageSize == '247x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*13) + 1};
    image = document.getElementById(image);
    var randomTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
    FadeImages(image, imageSize, randomNumber);
    var endlessLoop = setTimeout(function(){SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize)}, randomTimer);
}

function FadeImages(image, imageSize, randomNumber){
    $(image).fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(image).attr('src', '/halcyonic/images/collage_'  + imageSize + '_' + randomNumber + '.jpg').bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
            if(image.complete) $(image).fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: No error in console? And what is calling `SwitchImageLoop` the first time?

Comment: Along with the answer below, try to cut down on what the code is doing to isolate your problem. Try just getting the infinite loop to run, say outputting numbers or something simple. Then slowly add in features until something breaks.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, No, no error at all. Everything looks perfect on the console. If I tweak it a bit (removing the function() on the last line of first function) I get the recursive error.

Comment: @DiegoSagrera Is [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16908813/2324107) right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is when you are calling SwitchImageLoop inside setTimeout function. Your SwitchImageLoop accepts first parameter as string (id) but next time you calling your function inside setTimeout you are passing a document object as first parameter.

```
function SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize){
    if(imageSize == '110x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*15) + 1};
    if(imageSize == '247x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*13) + 1};
```

in next call document.getElementById(documentObject) will give you error

```
    image = document.getElementById(image);
    var randomTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
    FadeImages(image, imageSize, randomNumber);
    var endlessLoop = setTimeout(function(){SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize)}, randomTimer);
}
```

Rewrite your function to

```
    function SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize){
        if(imageSize == '110x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*15) + 1};
        if(imageSize == '247x110'){var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*13) + 1};
         var randomTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
        FadeImages(image, imageSize, randomNumber);
        var endlessLoop = setTimeout(function(){SwitchImageLoop(image, imageSize)}, randomTimer);
    }

    function FadeImages(image, imageSize, randomNumber){
       image=document.getElementById(image);    
       $(image).fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(image).attr('src', '/halcyonic/images/collage_'  + imageSize + '_' + randomNumber + '.jpg').bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
                if(image.complete) $(image).fadeIn(300);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and programming lesson @Sudhanshu Yadav. Thank you VERY much.

Answer (score 1):

I can see how `SwitchImageLoop` may work the first time when `image` is a string. The second time, however, you are passing a DOM element to it. I wonder what `document.getElementById` returns then. I suggest you remove line

```
image = document.getElementById(image);
```

and use `$("#" + image)` instead of $(image) where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your error, "too much recursive".

Your function is calling itself. Each time it calls itself it uses a bit more memory. The recursion depth is capped so that you don't crash your computer. You may wish to use a while loop rather than recursion for an endless loop.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp